# Display Voucher-Code on Prestashop Invoice. Simple SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, prestashop

I want to display the voucher code a customer entered for his order on the PDF-invoice. The code for fetching the cart rules for the specific invoice looks like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_cart_rule` ocr
WHERE ocr.`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id
```

This gets the amount of each voucher used, ID and so on, the voucher-codes itself however are located in a different table called "cart_rule". The two tables are connected by the "id_cart_rule" property. I want to join in the code for each cart rule so I can display it on the invoice. I guess it has to look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_cart_rule` ocr

LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` cr
ON ???

WHERE ocr.`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id);
```

I pretty much have no idea about SQL. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does both tables have id_cart_rule field?

Comment: Without know the table schemas it would be difficult to say.  Im guessing something like `cr.rule_id = ocr.rule_id`

Comment: yes, they are connected through that property

Comment: @haytem, The `order_cart_rule` table holds the rows for the used cart rules (vouchers) per order. The `cart_rule` table defines the cart rules itself which is where the code is stored (the field on that table is just called "code").

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_cart_rule` ocr

LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` cr
ON cr.code = ocr.id_order
WHERE ocr.`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id);

Answer (score 1):

Is this the query you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_cart_rule` ocr

LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_rule` cr
    ON ocr.id_cart_rule = cr.id_cart_rule

WHERE ocr.`id_order` = '.(int)$this->id
```

Tested and working on Prestashop 1.6.1.4